# Restart JMeter thread after stopped by error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, threadgroup

I set `JMeter Thread Group` *Action to be taken after a Sampler error* to `Stop thread` to prevent forwarding of error rate to further steps.

When error occurred in an iteration, thread is stopped, but not restarted in new iteration.

So rest of test is executed with decreased number of threads in this case and I' unable to restart these stopped threads.

Is there a way to restart stopped threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose `Start Next Thread Loop` it will restart thread with new iteration

> Start Next Thread Loop - ignore the error, start next loop and continue with the test

In Loop Count define at least 2 iterations so it can restart flow.

If you want it to execute only once fully add [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) with `Stop` and `Current Thread` at the end, so it will execute fully only once

> The "Stop" action stops the thread or test after completing any samples that are in progress.